# Auto update issue with drive C:/ in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I've created a program with ***Vb.net*** that includes an ***"auto-update"*** feature. I made it using ***File A Sync*** and it seems to work fine, But that's only when I set up the program in any drive except the ***"C:/"*** drive, But when I set up the program on the ***"C:/"*** drive, The download doesn't start at all. I do not know why. I also tried searching for this issue online but couldn't find any help.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Updater
    Dim client As New WebClient
    Private Sub Updater_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Downloading_Bar.EditValue = 0

        Speed_lb.Visible = True
        Speed_lb.Text = " 0 kb/s"
        Size_lb.Visible = True
        Size_lb.Text = " 0 MB's / 0 MB's"

        Try
            AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf Client_ProgressChanged
            AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf Client_DownloadCompleted

            client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(Program_URL), Application.StartupPath & "\Changer NewVersion.exe")

            Downloading_Bar.Properties.Step = 1
            Downloading_Bar.Properties.PercentView = True
            Downloading_Bar.Properties.Maximum = 100
            Downloading_Bar.Properties.Minimum = 0

        Catch ex As Exception
            DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Try
            Speed_lb.Text = String.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0).ToString("00"))
            Downloading_Bar.EditValue = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString()
            Downloading_Bar.PerformStep()
            Downloading_Bar.Update()

            Size_lb.Text = String.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0).ToString("0.00"), (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0).ToString("0.00"))

        Catch ex As Exception
            DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            client.CancelAsync()
            client.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        If Downloading_Bar.EditValue = 100 Then
            Try
                My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Changer.exe", "Changer OlderVersion.exe")
                My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Changer NewVersion.exe", "Changer.exe")

                Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath)
                Process.GetCurrentProcess.Kill()

                Me.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Updater_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        client.CancelAsync()
        client.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could be permission issue.

Comment: Is an error thrown? Can you show some sample code?

Comment: You cannot copy files like C:\pagefile.sys even as administrator. You should have a list of non paths to go, and also files that the system cannot copy. Before do the copy just check if the directory or file is in your non-copy list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The file I am trying to download is .exe file but the download isn't starting at all

Comment: I checked all permissions and also disabling ** Microsoft Windows defender and firewall ** and did not work too @crimson589

Comment: Can I get any help please?